# Canonical Tag Implementation on a PHP website

Tags: canonical-link

I have a PHP website. The head and footer are same on all pages. When I put a rel=canonical tag to the head of the homepage it is being settled for all other pages on the website. i.e when  , in the header of home page its shown the same canonical link for all other pages. What should I do? How can I add a canonical tag specific to all pages?

Comment: You put it in the header, which is included in all pages. So it appears on all pages. What is the problem?

Comment: I want different specific canonical for every page.

Comment: All pages point to the homepage as canonical. this is what happened to me.

Comment: So, the problem reduces to _how to create a function from url to its canonical representation_. But this is specific to every website, and you are not specified details, how should it decide what is canonical url for given url.